# UIScrollView remove subview animated

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

What I have:
Basically I have collection of UIViews presented in horizontal scrollView. UIScrollView have paging enabled and each item is not full screen so I can see part of previous and next view [based on this.](http://blog.proculo.de/archives/180-Paging-enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews.html)
Each view have delete button on itself.

What I need:
I need to find good idea to animate reloading UIScrollView content after removing one of the subview. As I thought about it there will be 4 different kinds of deletion:
1. deletion of last view
2. deletion of first view
3. deletion of middle view - hardest one
4. deletion of only view - easiest one, just animation of view disappearing

I need some suggestions/solutions.
Thanks,
Michal

edit:

Ok, I havent implemented it fully.

Here is reload method:

```
- (void)loadScrollView{
for(UIView* view in [_scrollView subviews])
{
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}

CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = 0;
int i = 0;

_scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
_scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
_scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

for(MPContact* contact in self.items)
{
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width*i;
    MyView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [view setFrame:frame];

    i++;
    [view.nameAndSurnameLabel setText:@"view text"];
    [view setDelegate:self];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:view];[self.viewsArray addObject:view];
}[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width*[self.items count], frame.size.height)];}
```

Each MyView have delete button with delegate, delegate removes view from viewsArray and run this method for now.

Comment: can you post your codes ( related parts ) ?

Comment: noted your edit. how about giving each view a tag ID, so that you can locate the view and remove them accordingly ?

Comment: I have method founding which view I want to delete, problem is what to do with other views after deleting this one (how to animate them smoothly in good position in scrollView)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use `+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion` method of `UIView` class. Just get your `UIView` that you want to delete, from `UIScrollView` and set `view.alpha = 0` in `animations` block. In `completion` block remove this `UIView` from `UIScrollView`, using `removeFromSuperView` method. Setting `alpha` to 0 will make fade animation.

**EDIT:**
Iterate all your views you want to move and change it's x coordinate.

```
for(UIView *view in scrollview.subviews)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
       [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.x-(/*HERE YOU NEED TO PUT WIDTH OF TOUR DELETING VIEW*/),view.y,view.width,view.heigh)];
   }
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
    //remove view from superview and change your uiscrollview's content offset.
   }];

}
```

Comment: I know how to do disappearing animation, but I need nice clean animation of reloading UIScrollView (if I wont reload it there will be hole, if I do there will be no animation of moving views in empty hole)

Comment: This helped me (needed to edit it to work on all 4 kinds of deletion).
Thanks

Comment: @user1315378, yes, this code moves all subviews. Upvote my answer and accept it please:)